# onclick get data from database using ajax laravel

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, laravel, laravel-5.4

What I am trying to do is to load `data-id` in drop-down menu when I click the list item, it need retrieve the data from db and append in table.

So far, I loaded the data id in drop-down menu and while on-click the list I send ajax call to retrieve data.

**My code (controller page):**

```
public function calcList($id)
{

    $designId=design::find($id);
    $design = design::select( `design_no`, `design_name`, `weight_length`, `quantity`, `design_image`, `des2`, `des3`, `des4`, `des5`, `des6`, `des7`)->where('id','=',$designId);
    // return Response::json(array('datas' => $design));
    // return response()->json(['data'=>$design]);
    return Response::json($design);
}
```

**Ajax Request:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.designList').click(function() {
        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            }
        });

        var id =($(this).attr("data-id"));
        $.ajax({
             type:"POST",
             url:"/calc_list/"+id,
             success : function(results) {
                 console.log(results);
             }
        }); 
    });
});
```

> On the console log, the results print like {..}
>   How to built the json to table?

Comment: Why are you using post method in the just retrieving data ?

Comment: @SagarGautam i dont want to reload the current page,without reloading i want to load data multiple time .  if there is any way to archive the same pls suggest me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to find designId. 
You just need to do

```
    public function calcList($id) {


    $design = design::select( `design_no`, `design_name`, `weight_length`, `quantity`, `design_image`, `des2`, `des3`, `des4`, `des5`, `des6`, `des7`)->where('id',$id)->get();  

    return Response::json($design);
}
```

You should not make another query to database by first finding a single design with id then using it again to get design_no, design_name, ... etc. It seems redundant.

Answer (score 2):

First, you'd better use `GET` method with `cache: false` ajax setting. In this case you don't need to pass `csrf` token.

Second, you forgot to use `get()` method to get data. Third, you can use `where` without `=`, it is by default.

```
use Response; // don't forget or use response()

public function calcList($id)
{
    $designId=design::find($id);
    $design = design::select( 'design_no', 'design_name', 'weight_length', 'quantity', 'design_image', 'des2', 'des3', 'des4', 'des5', 'des6', 'des7')->where('id', $designId)->get();
    return Response::json($design);
}
```

You can display your results as a table as follows.

```
<div id="destination"></div>
...
$.ajax({
         type:"POST",
         url:"/calc_list/"+id,
         success : function(results) {
             var $table = $('<table></table>');
             $('#destination').html('');

             for(var i=0;i<=results.length;i++) {
                 $table.append('<tr><td>No</td><td>'+results[i].design_no+'</td></tr>');
                 $table.append('<tr><td>Name</td><td>'+results[i].design_name+'</td></tr>');
             }
             $('#destination').append($table);
         }
    });
```

Comment: I am getting error Like this:
QueryException
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '' in 'field list' (SQL: select ``, ``, ``, ``, ``, ``, ``, ``, ``, ``, ``, ``, ``, ``, ``, ``, ``, ``, ``, ``, ``, ``, ``, ``, `` from `designs` where `id` = {"id":5,"design_no":"005","design_name":"Design-5","weight_length":"10gms","quantity":"10gms","design_image":null,"balls_7_pcs":"7","ravi_die":"2","balls_8_pcs":"3","rak_die":"2","balls_10_pcs":"4","deepak_die":"2","other_balls":"4","die_Gold":"2","kambi_2":"4","others":"2","kambi_3":"4"})

Comment: Which line? Do you pass wrong `$id` to the first line of the method?

Comment: i fix the above by replacing (`design` ->'design' )

Comment: iam getting result like this [..] how to built it to html @shukshin.ivan

Comment: It Showing -> calculation:37 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'design_no' of undefined

Comment: Well, try to `console.log(results[0])`. I actually can't debug it for yourself.

Comment: ya iam try to debug now i get the length of result console.log(results.length)  its show 0 .i cant able to find the problem where it is

Comment: Well, zero means zero results from DB. Harish, first move to `get` method to debug easily. Then just open url in browser and inspect, what it returns.

Comment: ya ok i'll try it

Comment: Thank you for u time to retify my error at last i go one solution after removed the find in controller it works  pls edit in ur above code it help others also

Answer (score 0):

You are checking the condition the wrong way. `find($id)` retrieve single RECORD, not the primary key. Modify your controller method.

```
public function calcList($id) {

    $design = design::select( `design_no`, `design_name`, `weight_length`, `quantity`, `design_image`, `des2`, `des3`, `des4`, `des5`, `des6`, `des7`)->where('id','=', $id)->get();   //*** change to id

    // return Response::json(array('datas' => $design));
    // return response()->json(['data'=>$design]);
    return Response::json($design);
}
```

More: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#retrieving-single-models

Also make sure you add this in your head

```
<meta name="_token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}" />
```